# Where is the journal article portlet in liferay?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I need to modify `liferay-portlet.xml` of Journal Article portlet. I searched a lot in the whole liferay with the keyowrd journal and found some results also but no liferay-portlet.xml is present in them. Do I need to download this portlet from some external source or if not, where is it present?

Comment: In `liferay-portlet.xml` you will find `<portlet-name>56</portlet-name>` that is Journal Content / Article portlet.

Comment: @Parkash: thanks for ur reply..I want to ask another thing-is it possible to export web content programmatically in liferay 6.2? See this link-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40014601/how-to-programmatically-export-web-content-to-a-lar-file-in-liferay-6-2

Comment: Yes it's possible. You might develop a custom plugin to scan and export journal article in the way you prefer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the list of portlet ids : https://web.liferay.com/fr/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Portlet+IDs

Comment: Link is broken now, thats why we should avoid link only answers..., :(